# Jquery - multiple conditional statements for one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-conditions

I have a popup window that needs to be hidden if there was a click on my site **or** on the Iframe.
What I would like to do is write a method like this:

```
if(click on my site || click on Iframe){
    hide window
}
```

I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
if($(document).click()===true  || $("#clientframe").contents().find(document)===true)(function(){
    $("#img-window").hide();
});
```

Comment: how about simle to add a new fuction?

Comment: it's not clear that what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What is `.method()`?

Comment: I would like to have a chunk of code that can be executed if any of the conditional statements are met

Comment: .method is just pseudocode for some generic jquery method

Comment: If a jQuery selector results in a collection of elements then the chain is executed, if not then it isn't (and fails silently). It feels like you should be using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter), or similar, but without some precision in what you want to do, and how, and based upon what (even a very simple real-world example should suffice) it's very hard to answer this question in an appreciable manner.

Comment: But `jQuery` object is always evaluated as `true`...

Comment: @Rayon, a jQuery object is always evaluated as true, regardless of the length of the contained collection, but methods don't always return that object, for example [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), when used without an argument, returns a String; [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), when used *with* an argument returns a Boolean.

Comment: @DavidThomas — True.. My comment was targeting OP about his post. Provided example does not clarify his point..

Comment: @Rayon: agreed, hence my vote-to-close (hopefully pending an edit to the question to clarify what the OP wants).

Comment: @cody  where you going to put this if condition? In order that it should execute?????

Comment: A few things: JavaScript (and therefore jQuery) generally works at a document level. So rather than using the term "my site" it might be better to think of it as "your document". An iframe element is an element within "your document" and thus is not separate from "your document". So, the question is, how do you use jQuery to listen to clicks on your document. The place to start in your quest is with [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/), and researching how events work in jQuery and JavaScript, especially [the information they bring with them](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is absolutely wrong. Function call is statement. You cant put statement as condition. Except it returns something. And they are event call. So there is no right place for that if condition. It doesn't matter you are using AND or OR operator. If you want to hide something on click of html element. Do something like this.

HTML

```
<button id='mysite' onclick='hided()'></button>
<button id='iframe' onclick='hided()'></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function hided()
{
// hide that dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing two methods as conditions.  I would avoid that as much as possible.  Method returns can be quite tricky in javascript.  Lookup the javascript truth table

https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Instead use more concrete returns from your methods.  Something like

```
$("#identifier").method()(function(){
    execute code here
    return true;
});
```

That way when you check the result in your if statement you will know what will happen.